# install entity framework 6.0.2 in visual studio 2012

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

i downloaded EFTools6.0.2ForVS2012.msi and installed it but it does not replace with older version of entity framework.
when i try to get version of entity framework it shows 4.
can anyone help me how to install entity framework 6.0.2 on visual studio 2012 without using nuget?

Comment: Is nuget throwing an error?

Answer (score 1):

There are some other actions you need to take, like renaming namespaces. You can find an article on migrations [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn469466)